# Evaluating $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(-1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$ without l'Hôpital Rule

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

> Before reading this post, I would suggest checking the following thread: [Is it possible to evaluate $\lim_{x\rightarrow 0}(-1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2116422/is-it-possible-to-evaluate-lim-x-rightarrow-0-1-cos-x-tan-x) The answers provided by other users and my further input could be helpful.

I have the following limit that I should evaluate without using l'Hôpital:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (-1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$$

Here's what I've done:
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} (-1+\cos x)^{\tan x}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{\ln((-1+\cos x)^{\tan x})}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{\tan x \cdot \ln(\cos x-1)}=\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} e^{\sin x \cdot \frac{\ln (\cos x-1)}{\cos x}}$$

but I'm stuck. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Is there a typo, since $-1+\cos x\le0$...

Comment: What does it means $(-1+\cos x)^{\tan x}$ for $x\to 0?$ Note that the basis is negative.

Comment: @OlivierOloa I just double-checked and yes, that's how the question is asked. And Wolfram seems to be able to find the [result.](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=limit+of+(-1%2Bcosx)%5Etanx+as+x-%3E0)

Comment: Have you tried splitting the exponent into real and imaginary part?

Comment: @Hyperplane Please excuse my lack of knowledge (I'm in high school), but how could that help?

Comment: Well as pointed out above you have $\cos(x)-1\le 0$ , hence you take the logarithm of a negative number above which immediately gives you complex numbers. I also noted that $\lim_{x\to 0 } Im \frac{\log(\cos(x)-1)}{\cos(x)} = i\pi$ (numerically)  so possibly it can help a lot to check what happens to real and imaginary part seperately.

Comment: How do you define logarithm for negative numbers?

Comment: You cant do this step $\ln (-1+\cos(x))^{\tan (x)}=\tan(x)\ln(-1+\cos (x))$ because $(-1+\cos (x))^{\tan(x)}$ is a complex number in almost all cases. However is true that $(-1+\cos(x))^{\tan (x)}=e^{\tan(x)\ln(-1+\cos (x))}$, because this is the definition for complex powers. P.S.: why the downvotes?

Comment: @Masacroso Could one solve $\lim_{x \rightarrow 0} \tan x \cdot \ln(\cos x-1)$ with l'Hôpital? I assume so, but even though I understand a negative number isn't possible within a logarithmic function, I think there could be solve way to evaluate the limit be it by using squeeze theorem or the definition of derivative. Would that be possible?

Comment: @Masacroso "The shortest path between two truths in the real domain passes through the complex domain." So just because at some point complex number occur you shouldn't rule out the calculation immediately. (note I didnt downvote you.)

Comment: @Glycerius you must divide the complex number in the real part and the imaginary part first, after you get the limit on each part, and if needed and possible you can use L'Hopital. But this decomposition on the real and imaginary part doesnt seem easy to do.

Comment: I got it, it more or less boils down to showing $\lim_{z\to 0} z\log(z) = 0$ for complex $z$.

Comment: Are you sure the expression is not $(1-\cos x)^{\tan x}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Claim: $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} (\cos(x)-1)^{\tan(x)} = 1$.
Proof: We will need the half angle and double angle formulas:

Half angle formula: $\cos(x) -1 = -2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2})$

Double angle formula: $\sin(x) = 2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})$

\begin{align}
(\cos(x)-1)^{\tan(x)}
  &= \text{exp}\Big( \tan(x)\log(-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))\Big)  \\
  &= \text{exp}\Big( \frac{\sin(x)}{\cos(x)}\log(-2\sin^2(\frac{x}{2}))\Big)  \\
  &= \text{exp}\Big(
     \frac{2\sin(\frac{x}{2})\cos(\frac{x}{2})}
       {\cos(x)}2\log(i\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2}))\Big)  \\
  &= \text{exp}\bigg(-i2\sqrt{2}
     \underbrace{\bigg(\frac{\cos(\frac{x}{2})}{\cos(x)}\bigg)}_{=:g(x)}
     \underbrace{\Big(i\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2})\Big)}_{=:f(x)}
     \log(i\sqrt{2}\sin(\frac{x}{2}))\bigg)  \\
\end{align}

And here we have $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} g(x) = 1$ and $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} f(x)\log(f(x)) = 0$, where the latter follows from $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}f(x) = 0$ and $\lim\limits_{z\to 0} z\log(z) = 0$ for complex $z$.

Hence $\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \text{exp}(-i2\sqrt{2}g(x)f(x)\log(f(x))) =  \text{exp}(0) = 1$

Answer (score 1):

I get the same result than Hyperplane from a slight different workaround. For $x\in\Bbb R$ we have that

$$\log (-1+\cos(x))=\log |-1+\cos(x)|+i\alpha(x)$$

where

$$\alpha(x)=\begin{cases}\pi,&\text{if }-1+\cos(x)<0\\{\rm undefined},&\text{if }-1+\cos(x)=0\end{cases}$$

Then

$$(-1+\cos(x))^{\tan(x)}=\exp\Big(\tan(x)\big(\log |-1+\cos(x)|+i\alpha(x)\big)\Big)$$

Then

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(-1+\cos(x))^{\tan(x)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\exp(\tan(x)\log |-1+\cos(x)|)$$

because $\lim_{x\to 0}\exp(i\tan(x)\alpha(x))=1$. To solve the last limit we can use L'Hopital:

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\tan(x)\log|-1+\cos(x)|=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\log|-1+\cos(x)|}{\cot(x)}=\\=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin^3(x)}{(\cos(x)-1)}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{\sin(x)(1-\cos^2(x))}{(\cos(x)-1)}=\lim_{x\to 0}-\sin(x)(1+\cos(x))=0$$

Then finally

$$\lim_{x\to 0}(-1+\cos(x))^{\tan(x)}=1$$